# NSConpoundPredicate filtering with second predicate

Tags: swift, filter, nspredicate

```
    let predicate: NSPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(starDate, endDate: endDate, options: HKQueryOptions.StrictStartDate)
    let metadatapredicate: NSPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjectsWithMetadataKey(HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, operatorType: .EqualToPredicateOperatorType, value: true)
```

I have two line code here, and didn't know how to filter predicate with metadatapredicate.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a compound predicate that matches samples that match both of those predicates?  You could use `NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubPredicates([predicate, metadatapredicate])` to combine them.